# Launching wordpress site w/out wordpress acccount?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I apologize in advanced if this is too simple of a question; but, 
I know you can install wordpress locally, and that hosting servers may have wordpress available.  Do you need a wordpress account at wordpress.com to launch a wordpress website on a host other than wordpress.com?

If so, is it possible to install plugins like woocommerce as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a wordpress.com account and yes, you can install the addons.